# Why levels panel is not refreshed or closed when loading model into the viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Opening the levels panel and then loading other model into the viewer, keeps the level panel open with levels data from a previous model. The panel must be closed and reopened to see levels from a current loaded model.

For instance, model browser panel closes automatically when switching between models. Levels panel should behave accordingly. Of course, it would be nice to have an option to keep the panel open and only have the data updated inside it.

Currently, the panel must be closed manually, e.g.

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_PRE_UNLOADED_EVENT, (extension) => {
  if (extension.extensionId === "Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension") {
    const levelsExtension = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension");
    if (levelsExtension?.levelsPanel?.isVisible()) {
      levelsExtension.levelsPanel.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
});
```